# PowerShell Split a String On First Occurrence of Substring/Character

Tags: string, powershell, split

I have a string that I want to split up in 2 pieces. The first piece is before the comma (`,`) and the second piece is all stuff after the comma (including the commas).

I already managed to retrieve the first piece before the comma in the variable `$Header`, but I don't know how to retrieve the pieces after the first `comma` in one big string.

```bsh
$string = "Header text,Text 1,Text 2,Text 3,Text 4,"

$header = $string.Split(',')[0] # $Header = "Header text"

$content = "Text 1,Text 2,Text 3,Text 4," 
# There might be more text then visible here, like say Text 5, Text 6, ..
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

PowerShell's `-split` operator supports specifying the maximum number of sub-strings to return, i.e. how many sub-strings to return.  After the pattern to split on, give the number of strings you want back:

```
$header,$content = "Header text,Text 1,Text 2,Text 3,Text 4," -split ',',2
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that is what I use now as you can read in my 'Comment' on Aug 19 at 13:09.

Comment: @DarkLite Oops. I didn't see that.

Comment: That's ok, no problem. Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Perfect Thanx for the tip @AaronJensen

Comment: Note that is you're splitting on a '.' then add a '\'.
$header,$content = "Header text.Text 1.Text 2.Text 3.Text 4." -split '\.',2

Answer (score 3):

Try something like :

```
$Content=$String.Split([string[]]"$Header,", [StringSplitOptions]"None")[1]
```

As you split according to a String, you are using a different signature of the function `split`.

The basic use needs only 1 argument, a separator character (more info about it can be found [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/06/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx#analyzing-methods-split-as-example), for instance). However, to use strings, the signature is the following :

```
System.String[] Split(String[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)
```

This is why you have to cast your string as an array of string. We use the `None` option in this case, but you can find the other options available in the `split` documentation.

Finally, as the value of `$Heasder,` is at the beggining of your `$String`, you need to catch the 2nd member of the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ploutox, I tried your suggestion with the example above, but the variable `$Content` stays empty. Very strange..

Comment: @DarkLite1 sorry I didn't try my answer before posting. Splitting with strings is a bit different than splitting with chars. I'll edit my answer acordingly

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I've found on the help of Microsoft the following `($String -split ",",2)[1]` which seems to work fine for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

method of Aaron is the best, but i propose my solution

```
$array="Header text,Text 1,Text 2,Text 3,Text 4," -split ','
$array[0],($array[1..($array.Length -1)] -join ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternate solution makes use of PowerShell's ability to distribute arrays to multiple variables with a single assignment. Note, however, that the `-split` operator splits on every comma and PowerShell's built-in conversion from Array back to String results in the elements being concatenated back together. So it's not as efficient as `String.Split`, but in your example, it's negligible.

```
$OFS = ','
$Content = 'Header text,Text 1,Text 2,Text 3,Text 4,'

[String]$Header,[String]$Rest = $Content -split $OFS

$OFS = ' '
Write-Host "Header = $Header"
Write-Host "Rest   = $Rest"
```

Finally, `$OFS` is a special variable in PowerShell that determines which character will be used when joining the array elements back into a single string. By default, it's a space. But it can be changed to anything.